# Silverlight 2.0 - scroll vertically, wrap horizontally

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-2.0, scroll, word-wrap

In silverlight 2.0. I have some content that i want to scroll vertically and wrap horizontally. In the controls I have a dock panel. The DockPanel's last child, which fills it, is a ScrollViewer

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.MyControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:WinControls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;
      assembly=Microsoft.Windows.Controls" 
    Width="400" Height="300">
    <WinControls:DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    ...
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MessageScroll" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" BorderThickness="0" >
    <Controls:TextDisplay x:Name="TextDisplay"></Controls:TextDisplay>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The TextDisplay control XAML looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.TextDisplay"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextDisplayText" TextWrapping="Wrap">
        </TextBlock>
</UserControl>
```

What I want to happen: The TextDisplay should occupy the main area of the control, 
with a vertical scrollbar if the height doesn't fit. The messages should wrap when they get too long horizontally.

The scrolling works, but now the messages don't wrap at the right-hand edge. they just cut off. It's not constraining the width, just hiding the HorizontalScrollBar. If I set HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" I can see them scrolling off to the right. How do i force it to wrap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility of the ScrollViewer to Disabled (or do not specify a value as Disabled is the default) then the TextDisplay will wrap correctly and the horizontal scroll bar will not be displayed.